Understanding Polynomial Long Division in a Quotient Ring
I'm trying to deepen my understanding how to do polynomial long division within quotient rings, and I've encountered a puzzling situation that I'd like to get some insights on.
Consider the quotient ring $R = \mathbb{F}[x, y] \big/ \langle x^2 + y^2 - 1 \rangle
$
I found that: $\frac{2x^2 - 1}{x + y} = y - x$
However, when I attempt to perform polynomial long division of using the standard long division algorithm, I encounter a looping process. After a few steps, the remainder cycles back to a form similar to the original dividend, causing the division to repeat indefinitely.
Is it possible and how to do polynomial long division in $R$?
